# Should client pull full object information or field only when required from REST?

Tags: java, rest

Current I has the below server scenario 
 
---------------------------------------------------------<sub>Redis Cache</sub> 
Client <--(Low Latency/instantly)--> REST API <----+
---------------------------------------------------------<sup>Database</sup>

Dude to the low latency between client and api i decided to do the cache at api side 
which also mean the client will not be caching 
then I start to think about the question 
Assume I have a `Person` class which contains `name` and `money` field that I have in my client 
and the API support fetching all `Person`'s information at once with `api.com/person` 
or fetching `Person`'s information one by one with `api.com/person?fields=name` and `api.com/person?fields=money`
should i request all of the information when the object is being created like this

```java
Class Person {

    String name;
    int money;

    public Person() {
        JsonObject data = getJsonData(`api.com/person`);
        this.name = data.get('name');
        this.name = data.get('money');
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getMoney() {
        return money;
    }
}
```

in this case, if the client only require `Name` of `Person`, but the object also pull the `money` from
server which is wasted for traffic or etc. 
or, i can replace the `getName()` function be like this

```
    public String getName() {
        JsonObject data = getJsonData(`api.com/person?fields=name`);
        return data.get('name');
    }
```

which does not waste any fields 
but the downside is, when client require both `Name` and `Money` field 
it would then double up the request required

I dont know which one is better for my case, any further explain are very welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a builder pattern to build person object by building proper url for fetching one or more fields in a single api hit. e.g.

```
 new PersonBuilder().addName().build(); // url attribute of PersonBuilder in this case should be "api.com/person?fields=name"
```

or

```
 new PersonBuilder().addName().addMoney().build(); // url attribute of PersonBuilder in this case should be "api.com/person?fields=name,money"
```

in build() method, you could call different setter methods based on what you added using addName(), addMoney() by maintaining different booleans in PersonBuilder corresponding to each field e.g. nameAdded = true, moneyAdded =false.

This way you will never need to hit the api multiple times.

Comment: impressive design! but there is a problem that if the class has lots of variables, this method would be a trouble and it double the workload of writing getter setter and now we need one more boolean for each variable

Comment: Actually, you won't need setters and boolean as well, you can just pass the org.json.JSONObject from api response to Person constructor and use opt methods e.g. optString(key, fallback) which return values if present or a fallback value. So you can set all the variables by querying the JSONObject passed irrespective of the variables which were added.

Comment: Ah i just did some research and found the same thing too! btw thank you a lots! answer accepted!